# ssrs sql server service pack 2 2008 cause error with query

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx

I have sql server 2008 services pack 1 64 bit . and I have report in ssrs
with this query in query designer:

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sum_AvgTime_WaitDist], [Measures].[Sum_AvgTime_WaitConfirm], [Measures].[TheDistribution_Count], [Measures].[Void_Dist_Price], [Measures].[Void_Dist_Count], [Measures].[Sum_AvgTime_Dist], [Measures].[Sale_Estimate_Price], [Measures].[Sum_AvgTime_Settle], [Measures].[Sum_AvgTime_Confirm], [Measures].[TheDistribution_Price], [Measures].[Sum_AvgTime_Delivered], [Measures].[Sale Price], [Measures].[Ret Dist Pure Price], [Measures].[Sale Count], [Measures].[Transfer To Next Month From Month Except Last Day], [Measures].[Transfer To Next Month], [Measures].[Order Count Last Day Order], [Measures].[Void_Sale_Price], [Measures].[Void_Sale_Count], [Measures].[Sale Price LD], [Measures].[Order Count Last Day Exit Dist], [Measures].[Exit Price LD], [Measures].[Transfer To Next Month From Month Last Day], [Measures].[BeenRejected_Count], [Measures].[BeenDelivered_NotSettled_Price], [Measures].[BeenRejected_Price], [Measures].[DuringTheVerification_Count], [Measures].[Convert_Price], [Measures].[Return Price], [Measures].[Sale_Estimate_Count], [Measures].[AreDistributed_Count], [Measures].[BeenDelivered_NotSettled_Count], [Measures].[AreDistributed_Price], [Measures].[FullBack_Price], [Measures].[FullBack_Count], [Measures].[Less_Price], [Measures].[RetDist_Pure_Price], [Measures].[RetDist_Pure_Count], [Measures].[FactorSettled_Count], [Measures].[DuringTheVerification_Price], [Measures].[FactorSettled_Price], [Measures].[ForwardPlanning_Price], [Measures].[ForwardPlanning_Count] }
  ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY {

  {[Dim Sale Office].[Zone Key].[Zone Key].ALLMEMBERS }* 
  {[Dim Sale Office].[Office Key].[All]} * 
  {[Dim Dist Branch].[Dist Branch Key].[All]}, 

  {[Dim Sale Office].[Zone Key].[All]} * 
  {[Dim Sale Office].[Office Key].[All]} * 
  {[Dim Dist Branch].[Dist Branch Key].[All]}, 

  {[Dim Sale Office].[Zone Key].[Zone Key].ALLMEMBERS} * 
  {[Dim Sale Office].[Office Key].[Office Key].ALLMEMBERS} * 
  {[Dim Dist Branch].[Dist Branch Key].[All]}, 

  {[Dim Sale Office].[Zone Key].[All]} * 
  {[Dim Sale Office].[Office Key].[All]} * 
  {[Dim Dist Branch].[Dist Branch Key].[Dist Branch Key].ALLMEMBERS}, 

  {[Dim Sale Office].[Zone Key].[Zone Key].ALLMEMBERS} * 
  {[Dim Sale Office].[Office Key].[Office Key].ALLMEMBERS} * 
  {[Dim Dist Branch].[Dist Branch Key].[Dist Branch Key].ALLMEMBERS }

   } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
   FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimSaleOfficeZoneKey, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
   FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimDateDay, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
   FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimDateMonth, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimDateYear, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube_SaleEstimateDashboard])))) WHERE ( IIF( STRTOSET(@DimDateYear, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@DimDateYear, CONSTRAINED), 
   [Dim Date].[Year].currentmember ), 
   IIF( STRTOSET(@DimDateMonth, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@DimDateMonth, CONSTRAINED), 
   [Dim Date].[Month].currentmember ), 
   IIF( STRTOSET(@DimDateDay, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@DimDateDay, CONSTRAINED), 
   [Dim Date].[Day].currentmember ) ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

as you can see this query has 4 parameter(Year,Month,Day,Zone)
it work fine for me.

but after I install service pack 2 2008

if I select one zone for parameter it give me error:

> "The MDx Function Failed Because The Coordinate For The 'Zone Key' Attribute Contains A set"

it work good for (all or For multi select Value for Parameter Zone.
but if I select Onley one zone For Parameter it give me error
why....?
And One More thing if I remove Non Empty From Axis The Error Message is gone

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `CONSTRAINED` from all `STRTOSET` formulas. I had a similar problem when I upgraded my SSRS solution to VS2012. I think this is related to tightening the securities against unqualified member names.